# Problems removing Regolith lnux

Tags: gnome, themes

A few days ago I installed the regolith Linux patch for Ubuntu, didn't like it so decided to remove it with commands:

```
sudo apt remove regolith-desktop
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:kgilmer/regolith-stable
```

And later used

```
dconf reset -f /
```

Now the desktop is back to normal but I cannot seem to install any additional softwares via terminal

and I  get error messages on terminal like

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 225536 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing regolith-gdm3-theme (1.03-1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package regolith-gdm3-theme (--remove):
 installed regolith-gdm3-theme package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 regolith-gdm3-theme
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry that my bug caused you difficulties Param Deshpande.  This bug has been fixed yesterday, so if you can update packages and take the latest you should then be able to cleanly uninstall all Regolith packages.  If that doesn't work and you are still stuck after Hamish Downer's suggestion, please let me know (kgilmer at gmail.com) and I'll work with you directly to fix it, or file an issue here: https://github.com/regolith-linux/regolith-desktop/issues

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I recently read [this article about regolith linux](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/06/install-regolith-linux-i3-gaps-ubuntu) and in the section "Uninstall the Regolith Desktop" it says:

> I tested uninstalling the desktop on Ubuntu 19.04 and it mostly went okay. I was left with an error about a missing ubuntu.css file in the GDM3 folder. I solved this by cloning the gnome-shell.css and renaming it to ubuntu.css.

I found these files in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/` so I guess the instructions for fixing in a terminal would be:

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/
ls
```

This would show whether there is a copy of `ubuntu.css`.  If there isn't you could then do:

```
sudo cp gnome-shell.css ubuntu.css
```

Good luck.